# HTML/Javascript Session Storage URL path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session, session-state

I am attempting to create a website based in webcomics. This webcomics page will have four different main tabs. Within these tabs, there will many comics shown, of which the user can browse through and click on whichever one they want. I looked into making the entire website ajax based, in the sense that it's one html page and therefore no whole page loading is required. I wanted to make it so the comics could appear dynamically, and then I would use session storage to store these comics so that the user could click back and forward to view the comics or different 'pages' they had seen.

From what I understand, this is what the two storage options are:

window.localStorage - stores data with no expiration date
window.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost when the browser tab is closed)

So I know I would like to use session storage because I'd like the user to return to the home screen after closing the browser.

My issue resides in the url path to the session states. Say a user sees a comic, and wishes to share this comic with other people (essentially the point of my website in terms of traffic). Is there a way to use session storage to also save url path to that state? And would this be permanent? So if the user is viewing comic "X", he could share this url with someone and they could also see the comic X. Perhaps what I'm asking for isn't even useful with session storage, but that's what I would like to learn. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is not so much local/session storage as it is URL handling. You'll want to look into using a framework, like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or [Aurelia](https://aurelia.io) that provides "routing" for you. You could also research "routing in single page applications". Basically, you want to provide the user with a URL they can share.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) is what you are looking for.